# Orchard CMS: Modules enabling or disabling not working

Tags: orchardcms

I have a web site built with Orchard CMS (v.1.10.2.0); I developed a custom module and installed it, and it is working, like other modules already installed.

My problem is that, starting from sometimes ago (I don't know exactly from when), if I try to enable or disable a module I encounter always an error about JetBrains.Annotations (see below for the full stack).

I can't debug the site (it is published on a server, it's not running on my machine); anyone knows how can I understand what problem is going on? Any advice on how to gain some information without debugging? (I'm quite new to Orchard).

> Oops. Something went wrong ... sorry
>   An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back
>
> One or more errors occurred.
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitlyAttribute' from assembly 'Orchard.Framework, Version=1.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.GetSourceFeatureNameForType(Type type, String extensionId) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.LoadFeature(FeatureDescriptor featureDescriptor) at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.CreateEntry(TKey k, Func`2 acquire) at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Get>b__0(TKey k) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory) at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) at Orchard.Caching.CacheManagerExtensions.Get[TKey,TResult](ICacheManager cacheManager, TKey key, Boolean preventConcurrentCalls, Func`2 acquire) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.<LoadFeatures>b__19_0(FeatureDescriptor descriptor) at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.TaskWithAcquireContext`1.Execute() at System.Linq.Parallel.ArrayMergeHelper`1.ToArrayElement(Int32 index) at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.ForAllEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TInput& currentElement, Int32& currentKey) at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork() at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work() at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean userInitiatedDispose) at System.Linq.Parallel.DefaultMergeHelper`2.System.Linq.Parallel.IMergeHelper<TInputOutput>.Execute() at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput, ParallelMergeOptions options, TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Boolean isOrdered, CancellationState cancellationState, Int32 queryId) at System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitionedStream) at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping, QuerySettings settings) at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream) at System.Linq.Parallel.ScanQueryOperator`1.ScanEnumerableQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient) at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient) at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings) at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.RunSynchronously() at System.Linq.Parallel.ArrayMergeHelper`1.Execute() at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.ExecuteAndGetResultsAsArray() at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.RunInParallel[T,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.LoadFeatures(IEnumerable`1 featureDescriptors) at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at Orchard.Modules.Controllers.AdminController.FeaturesPOST(FeaturesBulkAction bulkAction, IList`1 featureIds, Nullable`1 force) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitlyAttribute' from assembly 'Orchard.Framework, Version=1.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.GetSourceFeatureNameForType(Type type, String extensionId) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.LoadFeature(FeatureDescriptor featureDescriptor) at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.CreateEntry(TKey k, Func`2 acquire) at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(TKey k) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory) at Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) at Orchard.Caching.CacheManagerExtensions.Get[TKey,TResult](ICacheManager cacheManager, TKey key, Boolean preventConcurrentCalls, Func`2 acquire) at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager.b__19_0(FeatureDescriptor descriptor) at Orchard.Caching.DefaultParallelCacheContext.TaskWithAcquireContext`1.Execute() at System.Linq.Parallel.ArrayMergeHelper`1.ToArrayElement(Int32 index) at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.ForAllEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TInput& currentElement, Int32& currentKey) at System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork() at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work() at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this issue a few times. The problem is that the Extension Manager tries to load an assembly (probably a custom module) that contains references to JetBrains annotation classes which were compiled into the `Orchard.Framework` assembly but were removed at some point due to conflicts with other assemblies which contained classes with the same name.

The only solution I found was to remove all usages of JetBrains annotation attributes from custom modules.

Comment: I thought to a problem like yours, but I have only a custom module and it does not contain any references to JetBrains annotation: Probably it's a module that I installed from the gallery, but now I can't disable anything because I get the error everytime.

Comment: That's possible, especially if the module was developed with an older version of Orchard core. Try using the Orchard.exe shell from your application's bin folder. You can use the command `feature disable feature-name` to disable a feature. If that fails too, then you can go to the Orchard database and disable the feature manually in `ShellFeatureStateRecord` table (set `EnableState` to `Down`).

Comment: It worked! It was the module TinyMce.Settings causing the problem; after uninstalling it all started to works again. Thanks!